# SQL Case Sensitive Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have two databases which return different results based on the case of the query.

On the first database I run the query

```
FROM [Temp].[Team].[CLASS]
  WHERE [TABLE_NAME] like '%Link%'
```

and on the other database I run this query

```
FROM [Temp].[Team].[CLASS]
  WHERE [TABLE_NAME] like '%LINK%'
```

The first query returns nothing but the second query returns what I'd expect it to.

Checking the collation between the databases, I find they are both set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` so I wouldn't expect them to behave differently.

What other settings do I need to alter to give me case insensitive queries without changing my queries?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411161/sql-server-check-case-sensitivity

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? If so, please tag your question for that DBMS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to check that the collation of the servers and columns match (collation isn't only determined at the database level).

To check the servers:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('COLLATION');
```

To check the columns (a much, much, much more likely culprit for this symptom IMHO):

```
SELECT collation_name
  FROM [Temp].sys.columns AS c
   INNER JOIN [Temp].sys.objects AS o ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
   INNER JOIN [Temp].sys.schemas AS s ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE UPPER(c.name = N'TABLE_NAME')
  AND UPPER(o.name = N'CLASS')
  AND UPPER(s.name = N'TEAM');
```

If these don't match, then your choices are:

1. Make them match. E.g. on the server where the collation is case sensitive, you can make it not case sensitive using:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [Team].[CLASS] 
     ALTER COLUMN [TABLE_NAME] VARCHAR(32) -- guessing
     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
     NOT NULL; -- also guessing
   ```
2. Use a case-insensitive query, e.g.

   ```
   WHERE UPPER([TABLE_NAME]) LIKE '%LINK%';

   -- or

   WHERE [TABLE_NAME] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
     LIKE '%LINK%';
   ```

Also be sure to use an `N` prefix if the column is `NVARCHAR`.